# Hessian of Loss function ( Applying Newton's method in Logistic Regression )

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, logistic-regression

If Cost function is L ,
$$ L=−(\frac{1}{m})(y(log(h(x))+(1−y)( log(1−h(x) ) ) $$ 
$$ h(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(w^{T}x+b)}} $$
First order partial deriavative of L with respect to w is ,
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = - ( \frac{1}{m} ) ( h(w) - y )x $$ 
**Question :**
 **how do i find the second order partial derivative of L with respect to w ?, that is** $$ \frac{\partial ^{2}L}{\partial w^{2}}$$  
So that i can compute the error gradient by using Newton's method and update Weights $ w $, like this 
$$ w_{new} = w_{old} - (\frac{\partial ^{2}L}{\partial w^{2}})^{-1} \ ( \frac{\partial L}{\partial w}) $$ 
 Am just trying to figure out how *Newton's method* works with *logistic regression*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $f(x)$ has to satisfy the condition where its *hessian* has to be
$$\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R^{1}$$
Meaning that $f(x)$ has to be *twice differentiable* and it is *positive semi-definite.*

we already know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3244120/693769) that ,

$$ \frac{\partial L} { \partial w} = (h_\theta(x) - y)x $$
$$ \sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(w^Tx+b)}}$$ 
Refer here for [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225116/693769) on first deriavative of $ \sigma(x)$ ,
$$  \sigma^{'}(x) = \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x)) $$

> Please note that here $ h_\theta(x) $  and $ \sigma(x) $ are one and the same , i just used $ \sigma(x)$ for representation sake.

Now we need to find $ \frac{\partial^2 L}{ \partial w^2} $ ,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 L}{ \partial w^2} &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial w}(xh_\theta(x) - xy) \\ \\
&= x^2 \frac{\partial L}{\partial w} (h_\theta(x)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [ \ h_\theta^{'}(x) = \sigma^{'}(x) \ ] \\ \\
&= x^2 ( \sigma(x) - \sigma(x)^2) \\ \\
& (or) \\ \\
&= x .( \sigma(x) - \sigma(x)^2).x^{T}
\end{align*}
$$
Am hoping that am correct !

Comment: How could you have answered the question if you haven't even formulated one?

Comment: I have ignored the unwanted parts & framed the question clearly now ! @mathreadler Is my implementation of answer is correct if not can you provide me an answer ? Thank you

Comment: Here's the [proof](http://mathgotchas.blogspot.com/search/label/Logistic%20Regression) for my answer @mathreadler

Answer (score 2):

It is not so clear that you get these concepts.

You should clarify inputs and outputs. What you seem to have done is calculated second derivative of a scalar valued function of one variable. In other words : $$\mathbb R^{1} \to \mathbb R^{1}$$
function. Jacobians take all different partial differentials with respect to all different input variables. For a function $$\cases{x \in \mathbb R^n\\f(x) \in \mathbb R^m}$$

you get an output that is a $n\times m$ **matrix**.

For a Hessian to be a matrix we would need for a function $f(x)$ to be
$$\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R^{1}$$

the more general case

$$\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R^{m}$$

it will be a 3 indexed [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor).

Comment: Since I am a beginner i got an idea about the gradients , tensor which is a n-dimensional vector representation. As far second order optimization i am just starting off so Please enlighten me !

Comment: I think your derivation of second order derivative is correct, I just wanted to point out that we usually use multivariable functions when talkning of Jacobians and Hessians.

Comment: i just dont how these things add up to minimizing the loss function as this$ L=−(\frac{1}{m})(y(log(h(x))+(1−y)( log(1−h(x) ) ) $, where $h(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^-{wx+b}}$ , m = len of vector x and how did L became $\frac{dL}{dw} = - ( \frac{1}{m} ) ( h(x) - y )x $ ?

Comment: Keep reading. Probably something you missed.

Comment: you saying that the function has to be positive semi-definite for  newton's method to work ? can you brief me on that please

Comment: @guru_007 : Sorry it's a bit too many question at once and you also change them over time. This kind of discourages people from answering. Newton method needs some properties to converge. Maybe you can make a new question about that specifically?

Comment: I have figured the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3321299/693769) myself can you verify whether its correct ? @mathreadler

Answer (score 1):

For the second derivative, you could do is faster
$$\sigma' (x)= \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))=\sigma(x)-\sigma^2(x)$$
$$\sigma'' (x)=\sigma' (x)-2 \sigma (x)\sigma' (x)=\sigma' (x)(1-2\sigma (x))=\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))(1-2\sigma (x))$$ which is not what you obtain.

**Edit**

In order to check the result, let us use the second-order central derivative 
$$f''(x)  =  \frac{f(x+h) - 2 f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^{2}}$$
at $x=\frac 12$ and $h=\frac 1 {200}$.

This would give $-0.0575566$ while the formula I wrote gives $-0.0575568$; your formula leads to $0.292561$.

At least, we do not agree.

Comment: But mine is so simpler than yours !

Comment: @guru_007. Simpler, not sure ! Is your correct ?

Comment: Leiboivici am preety sure about it but am having trouble how does it add to deriving $\frac{d^{2}L}{dx^{2}} $, where $ L=−(\frac{1}{m})(y(log(h(x))+(1−y)( log(1−h(x) ) ) $, where $ h(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^-{wx+b}} $ and $\frac{dL}{dw} = - ( \frac{1}{m} ) ( h(w) - y )x $

Comment: @guru_007. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you , @ClaudeLeibovici that's neat ! still i dont know how it helps me ! my edit is clear now

Comment: @guru_007. It is not good to change the problem

Comment: Sorry , i wasn't clear ! but your answer was right to my previous question lets agree that

Comment: Changing problems after answer has been gotten is not nice. It will give bad responses and probably fewer answers in the future.

Comment: Sorry i shouldn't have changed the question after the answer has been given already. I have figured the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3321299/693769) what's your opinion about it .! @ClaudeLeibovici is it right ?